# How to include name of parent folder in file names created in an also created subdirectory?

Tags: batch-file

First of all, thanks for all the answered questions about this subject, helped me a lot.

I created a batch file that created folders and dummy files because we use the structure for different customers over and over.

Its pretty simple:

```
mkdir "0. Folder 0"
mkdir "1. Folder 1"
mkdir "2. Folder 2"
mkdir "3. Folder 3"
mkdir "4. Folder 4"
mkdir "5. Folder 5"
mkdir "6. Folder 6"
mkdir "7. Folder 7"
mkdir "8. Folder 8"

type nul > "3. Folder 3"\"ADMIN - Random Dummy filename".xlsx
type nul > "3. Folder 3"\"ADMIN - Random Dummy filename".pdf
type nul > "3. Folder 3"\"ADMIN - Random Dummy filename".pdf
type nul > "3. Folder 3"\"ADMIN - Random Dummy filename".xlsx
```

Now comes my question, it would be super if the client folder we create these subfolders be appended in the name.

For example:
Client name: TEST_CLIENT_2015_FINAL

Result:
TEST_CLIENT_2015_FINAL\3. Folder 3\TEST_CLIENT_2015_FINAL - Random Dummy filename.pdf

Hopefully someone can help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this batch file if it is executed in directory **TEST_CLIENT_2015_FINAL**:

```
@echo on
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Get name of current working directory.
for /F "delims=" %%D in ("%CD%") do set "ParentFolder=%%~nxD"

rem Create subdirectories in current working directory from 0 to 8 in steps of 1.
rem And create in each subdirectory 2 files with name of current directory in name.
for /L %%V in (0,1,8) do (
    set "FolderName=%%V. Folder %%V"
    mkdir "!FolderName!"
    type nul>"!FolderName!\%ParentFolder% - Random Dummy filename.pdf"
    type nul>"!FolderName!\%ParentFolder% - Random Dummy filename.xlsx"
)
endlocal
```

To understand the used commands, open a command prompt window and run:

- `for /?`
- `mkdir /?` or `md /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Starting a command with parameter `/?` outputs help of this command.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be asking is, "How can I use variables in batch scripting?"

Just like in algebra:

```
5 * x = 10
```

You can infer that `x = 2`.  Same sort of convention is available in just about all scripting languages.  In batch scripting, you *set* a variable by

```
set "x=10"
```

with no spaces on either side of the equal sign.  Then to retrieve the value of `x`, enclose it in `%` signs.  If you did

```
set "x=10"
echo %x%
```

... then `10` would print to the screen.

That's it for the basics.  The next step is to understand `for` loops.  A `for` loop lets you repeat the same command or block of commands over and over, with a variable that changes with each iteration.  For example:

```
for %%I in (apples oranges pineapples) do echo %%I
```

... would echo

```
apples
oranges
pineapples
```

See how that works?  As you've probably noticed, `for` loops interact with variables with a little different syntax, having the percent signs on the left side.

That's probably enough of the basics for you to understand the solution I'm offering below.

Looks like your script has quite a bit of repetition, just with incrementing numbers.  I think it'd be a lot easier to use a couple of loops to create your test structure.

```js
@echo off
setlocal

rem // optional syntax: script.bat "client name"
set "client=TEST_CLIENT_2015_FINAL"
if not "%~1"=="" set "client=%~1"

rem // md is a synonym for mkdir
md "%client%"

rem // let %%I=I+1, starting at 0 and ending with 8
for /L %%I in (0,1,8) do (

    md "%client%\%%I. Folder %%I"

    rem // Run the same command, letting %%e=xlsx the first loop, pdf the next
    rem // You can add docx, pptx, and other extensions here if you wish.
    for %%e in (xlsx pdf) do (
        type NUL > "%client%\%%I. Folder %%I\%client% - Random Dummy filename.%%e"
    )
)
```